# MATLAB/Simulink 3rd party target compilation error HRESULT = 80040154

Tags: c#, c++, matlab, dll, simulink

Good morning,

I'm running into issues trying to compile a Simulink model for a 3rd party target, in this case vTAG. Whenever I try and build my app, a 
`### Making extended map file extended_vc.map
CoCreateInstance failed - HRESULT = 80040154 
make: *** [extended_vc.map] Error -1 
The make command returned an error of 2. An error occurred during the call to make.` 
error message is displayed. I'm using MATLAB 2016b 64-bit running Visual Studio 2013 compiler.

Now, I'm not a windows power user by any stretch, but my research so far indicates that this error message related to a .dll registry issue in Windows with regards to a 64-bit compiler unsuccessfully trying to access a 32-bit .dll. Therefore I tried to compile my app with a 32-bit version of MATLAB (2015b with Visual Studio 2010 compiler), but I was presented with the exact same error message. This strikes me as rather odd given the nature of the `HRESULT = 80040154` error code.

The Simulink model I am trying to compiled has been verified as ok and has compiled on other machines so I can discount that as the cause of the issue. Furthermore other models which I built which would export successfully to vTAG on my machine previously now do not export and return the same `HRESULT = 80040154` error message now. I contacted MATLAB support and they said they couldn't help as it was regarding a 3rd Party .dll. They got me to run an example compilation to a generic target (which ran okay), but that is an unsuitable target due to the nature of the model and the other 3rd party componentry it uses. I'm trying to avoid contacting vTAG support.

It seems to me the simple way to fix this would be to run `Regsvr32` and re-register the offending .dll correctly. However I do not know how to locate the correct .dll to register it. I've tried using the built in repair functions on the versions of Visual Studio I mention, although this has not solved the issue.

Therefore, my question is how would I go about locating this offending .dll in order to deploy the `Regsvr32` command to register it? I'm reticent to jump into applying the fixes listed here regarding the error message, as I have tried using the 32-bit version of MATLAB as a work around and this has not worked. Have any other MATLAB/Simulink users come across this issue before and know of any other workarounds to get apps to export with this error message?

Thanks in advance for any light anyone can shed on this!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the issue solved.

For anyone else who encounters this issues with MATLAB and using a 3rd party compiler to build for a 3rd party target, the .dll causing the issue will be located in the installation directory of the tool-set responsible for compilation to the 3rd party target. Registering the .dll with `Regsvr32` does the trick as expected.